# How to tell which packages will be installed by snap

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

I just discovered that chromium is released as a snap package in my Ubuntu 20.04, and I'd like to know what else are like this. So,

How can I tell which packages come from snap? I.e., I want to have a list of packages that on trying to install using APT actually installs Snaps.

Comment: I've removed the snaps from my system, and I want to avoid any packages that released in snap.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it happened since 19.10 when I was looking to solve my Chromium snaps mount --rbind Permission denied problem. Glad to know it is not happening to other packages, as I've removed the snaps from my system and don't want to bring it back in again.

Comment: You can `snap list` to list your installed snaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition of Chromium browser to a snap package was planned since 19.10 and was [announced](https://snapcraft.io/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition#:~:text=We%20have%20recently%20announced%20that,the%20snap%20in%20Ubuntu%2019.10) on Snapcraft Blog. As of now I'm not aware of any other package with which with such transition happened.

You can always refer to package details on [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com) or the output of `apt show package` and check if it's dummy package and depends on snap. For example, in case of Chromium browser, [package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/chromium-browser) mentions:

> Transitional package - chromium-browser -> chromium snap

The output of `apt show` also mentions that it is a dummy package and can be safely removed.

```
$ apt show chromium-browser
Package: chromium-browser
Version: 81.0.4044.129-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/web
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 164 kB
Provides: gnome-www-browser, www-browser, x-www-browser
Pre-Depends: debconf, snapd
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Homepage: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/
Download-Size: 48.4 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Transitional package - chromium-browser -> chromium snap
 This is a transitional dummy package. It can safely be removed.
 .
 chromium-browser is now replaced by the chromium snap.
```